# Return HTTP codes from jersey Chunked response when in error

Tags: java, rest, https, jersey-2.0

I've got three services like those described with chunked response in the jersey documentation:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html

but I've got to add user access control and respond accordingly with 403 error codes but found no way on adding status to the response or build an error response like those in services returning entity body types.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return `Response` instead of `ChunkedOutPut` and then wrap `ChunkedOutPut` or error message inside your `Response` object as shown below.

```
@GET
public Response getChunkedResponse() throws IOException {
    // Check access here
    if (!authorized()) {
        Response.status(403).entity("No Access").build();
    } else {
        final ChunkedOutput<String> output = new ChunkedOutput<String>(String.class);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // Your operation which returns chunked output.
            }
        }.start();
        return Response.ok(output).build();
    }
}
```